# I am going mixed

Tags: linear-algebra

Why this is wrong ?

$ -1=(-1)^{2/2}=((-1)^{2})^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1 $

**Then**

$1=-1$

Comment: the folks at math.stackexchange will tell you $(-1)^{2/2}\neq((-1)^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: Why it is not equal.

Comment: 1^(1/2)=+/-1. you then take the -1 to match the LHS.

Comment: $((a)^{m})^{n}=((a)^{n})^{m}$

Comment: Step 2 -> Step 3 is wrong. The `Order` of evaluation matters.

Comment: @YvesKlett And also for the title... :)

Comment: LOL the tags are awesome.

Comment: @Masoud The rule $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$ is not true for all $a$, $m$, $n$. Generally when that rule is taught, these variables are assumed to be positive.